# Can I take a fully-charged portable phone charger on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, uk, airport-security

It's a PowerAdd Power Bank Mobile Phone Backup Charger

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No.

Source: https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/lithium-battery-guidance-document-2017-en.pdf

> Lithium ion batteries packed by themselves (Packing Instruction 965) (not contained in or packed with equipment):
>   (a) must be shipped at a state of charge (SoC) not exceeding 30% of their rated design capacity

Now, the battery within your power pack *is contained within equipment*, so to all appearances that's no issue. It's not a battery, after all, it's equipment with a battery inside.

However:

> Power Bank (power pack, mobile battery, etc.). These are portable devices designed to be able to charge consumer devices such as mobile phones and tablets. For the purposes of this guidance document and the IATA Dangerous Goods Regulations, power banks **are to be classified as batteries** [...] For carriage by passengers, power banks are considered spare batteries [...]

So, the power bank itself *is a battery*. And thus, no more than 30% charge.

Comment: That's interesting. Which airlines have adopted this guidance? I'm regularly travelling with a high capacity power bank, fully charged. The Chinese airports like to take a long hard look at it, but no one has ever asked me how charged it is.

Comment: So I checked, the UK Civil Aviation Authority [doesn't mention the state of charge](https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/Before-you-fly/Baggage/Items-that-are-allowed-in-baggage/) of lithium ion batteries. Perhaps this question should be better constrained by geography.

Comment: I am not an expert on Dangerous Goods, but I am not sure that your reading of these regulations is correct.  In particular, I think the term "shipped" may not apply to carry-on baggage.  There is [a separate regulation](http://www.lan.com/upload/pdf/seccion-2-3-en.pdf) on "dangerous goods carried by passengers or crew" which specifically permits "spare batteries" to be carried, within certain limits but with no mention of a maximum charge level.

Comment: Certainly I have never seen any airline or government aviation regulator communicate such a requirement to passengers.

Comment: Have declared and taken them on many international flights, all I'ev been told is not in checked luggage.

Comment: I don't think this is correct...... it's a hot topic, and seems to be well-defined specifically for these battery packs (used mostly for phones).  Look at the linked duplicate.